# Postgres database on Kubernetes is being slow sporadically

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have Postgres database on a pod in Kubernetes. When I run the same query over and over again, it takes from 4ms to 30seconds. I'm stuck and I don't know what could be causing it. So what could possibly be causing it?
Thanks

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for a slow and a fast execution to the question. Ideally, turn on `track_io_timing` first.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you

1. take @Laurenz comment serious and analyze both fast and slow queries by running EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) before command.

You will have something like

```
explain analyze select sum(countstarted), starttime from CompositionElementAggregate1 group by starttime;
                                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                              
                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------
 Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=55246.24..55252.74 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=4579.309..4688.106 rows=4611 loops=1)
   Group Key: starttime
   ->  Sort  (cost=55246.24..55247.24 rows=400 width=40) (actual time=4579.281..4623.522 rows=13808 loops=1)
         Sort Key: starttime
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1463kB
         ->  Gather  (cost=55186.45..55228.95 rows=400 width=40) (actual time=4454.649..4531.503 rows=13808 loops=1)
               Workers Planned: 2
               Workers Launched: 2
               ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=54186.45..54188.95 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=4451.450..4469.493 rows=4603 loops=3)
                     Group Key: starttime
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on compositionelementaggregate1  (cost=0.00..51661.63 rows=504963 width=16) (actual time=0.049..2260.735 row
s=585297 loops=3)
 Planning time: 0.113 ms
 Execution time: 4702.844 ms
(13 rows)
```

2. there are 2 good articles, read them - they explain how to [TO DETECT SLOW QUERIES IN POSTGRESQL](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/3-ways-to-detect-slow-queries-in-postgresql/) and [How to Identify PostgreSQL Performance Issues with Slow Queries](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/how-identify-postgresql-performance-issues-slow-queries)

Most probably issue only inside `postgresql`, not `kubernetes` itself